# How to change font colour of matInput placeholder

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, placeholder

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

I need to change colour of the tag "Email" by default it is black.
I tried style="color:blue" still no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the placeholder color to blue by adding this css code

```css
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.custom-placeholder::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #161c1d !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom-placeholder::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #161c1d !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom-placeholder:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #161c1d !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom-placeholder:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #161c1d !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl" class="custom-placeholder" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

where custom-placeholder is class added on input

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question properly, but if you want to change the color of the placeholder text try this css:

```
::placeholder { 
  color: blue;
  opacity: 1; 
}
```